# Embarcader : which version of Turbopower Async Pro is compatible for XE10

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I need to install Turbopower Async Pro. So my question is which version of Turbopower Async Pro is compatible for XE10.4 (RAD Studio Sydney).
I have AsyncPro Release 5.0.0. Will it work with XE10.4 (RAD Studio Sydney)?

Comment: There is no such thing as XE10. You tagged the question XE7. Can you fix this please and make it clear which version you are referring to.

Comment: XE8 was the last version in the XE series. Then they changed the version scheme with 10.0, where 10.0 - 10.4 are major versions and 10.0.x - 10.4.x are updates. Then they changed the scheme again with 11.0, where 11.x are updates (the current version is 11.1).  So, are you asking for help with a real XE version, or a 10.x version? They are completely different.

Comment: This is for XE10.4 IDE (RAD Studio Sydney).

Comment: The old TurboPower stuff was released as opensource. One source of a maintained version is TurboPack. Their packages are available through GetIt from within the IDE. Tools -> GetIt Package Manager then search for AsyncPro.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for TurboPack\AsyncPro on GitHub. The sources there contain packages for Delphi 10 (Berlin) to 11 (Alexandria), which includes 10.4 (Sydney).

But I haven't tried it myself.